# InteropForms class method not visible in VB6

Tags: vb6-migration

I have built a simple InteropForms class using the project template in VS 2010. It builds successfully and registers the library in the system. I can see it and reference it in VB6 but none of the public methods or properties I add to the class in VS2010 are visible.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Imports Microsoft.InteropFormTools

<InteropForm()> _
Public Class frmWebBrowserPreview
    Private Sub frmWebBrowserPreview_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Windows.Forms.Keys.Escape Then Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmWebBrowserPreview_MouseUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
        Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub wbrPreview_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles wbrPreview.DocumentCompleted
        wbrPreview.Visible = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Navigate to the specified URL
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="strURL">The URL string</param>
    Public Function Navigate(strURL As String) As Boolean
        wbrPreview.Navigate(strURL)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Which project template are you referring to?

Comment: I had never even heard of the Microsoft Interop Forms Toolkit. It looks unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template comes from the toolkit: VB6 InteropForm Library

It's not supported in VS2012 (yet...)...
[Toolkit for VS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/04/15/interop-forms-toolkit-2-1-update-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

I figured it out. You have to add an InteropFormMethod attribute to the method in question and then rebuild the wrapper.

```
    ''' <summary>
''' Navigate to the specified URL
''' </summary>
''' <param name="strURL">The URL string</param>
<InteropFormMethod()> _
Public Function Navigate(strURL As String) As Boolean
    wbrPreview.Navigate(strURL)
End Function
```

Comment: I recently upgraded to VS2012 and the Toolkit seems to be working. Also, the navigate method in question is visible in VB6 and working correctly. However, I've marked this as the answer as I think it is correct.